# CompareValidator is missing values

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, comparevalidator

I have two text box controls, txtPassword and txtPassword2 on a web form.

Using a CompareValidator control, both fields need to match.

```
txtPassword = "" 
txtPassword2 = "" 
No compare error 
txtPassword throws it's required field error

txtPassword = "1" 
txtPassword2 = "" 
No compare error

txtPassword = "" 
txtPassword2 = "1" 
Compare error 
txtPassword throws it's required field error

txtPassword = "1" 
txtPassword2 = "2" 
Compare error
```

Any idea why it's missing blank values for txtPassword2?

Here's the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Text="" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword2" Text="" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match!" ControlToValidate="txtPassword2" ControlToCompare="txtPassword"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: I don't remember about CompareValidator but RegularExpressionValidator doesn't work for empty data. So you need RequiredFieldValidator still. I think here's the same. Add the 2nd one.

Comment: You need to add a RequiredFieldValidator for txtPassword2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` only for `txtPassword`, so if `txtPassword2` left blank will not throw required field error. one thing you need to add is `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` for `txtPassword2`, and also you need to specify the validation group. hence the code will be like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Text="" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ValidationGroup="checkNull"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword2" Text="" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="txtPassword2" ValidationGroup="checkNull"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match!" ControlToValidate="txtPassword2" ControlToCompare="txtPassword"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: That works fine, but isn't totally what I am after.
txtPassword is a required field, txtPassword2 isn't a required field (technically). Because txtPassword is required, something has to be entered, and because txtPassword2 has to match txtPassword that makes it required (without using a required field validator).
The major issue I am trying to overcome is the form being posted when txtPassword isn't blank, but txtPassword2 is blank. They don't match, so why isn't it catching it? Sorry for the long comment, I hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I wanted the password to be required during "insert" and used `RequiredFieldValidators` to ensure both password boxes were completed with a `CompareValidator` making sure they matched.

In edit mode, i had the `RequiredFieldValidators` turned off and ran into the same problem, the PasswordConfirm `Textbox` didn't stop a match if it was left blank.

I solved this by using 2 `CompareValidators` as so with the `ControlToValidate` and `ControlToCompare` fields swapped.  This forced them to validate each other so that if anything was typed in either one, it forced a check

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPassword" ControlToCompare="tbConfirmPassword"  Type="String" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="<br />The new passwords do not match" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbConfirmPassword" ControlToCompare="tbPassword"  Type="String" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="<br />The new passwords do not match" />
```